# Why isn't Sublime Text 2 affected by system wide font rendering settings?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, cleartype, sublime-text-2

I've always thought my font looked too fat and blurry in Sublime Text 2, almost as if it's constantly bold, so I decided to open Gedit and Sublime Text side by side and compare. Indeed, all fonts look much sharper and clearer in Gedit. I confirmed that the system wide settings (Appearance->Fonts->Rendering) has no effect in Sublime Text 2 by changing them and watching Gedit following the changes, and Sublime Text 2 staying exactly the same.

Why isn't Sublime Text 2 affected by system wide font rendering settings?

Answer (score 1):

You should look in your Sublime Text user settings – the file `Preferences.sublime-settings` in `\Sublime Text 2\Packages\User\` – if there's a font setting, especially a `font_options`.

If this is the case, this setting will override your system-wide settings.